# Share session data between another PHP application and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two domain in same hosting one is using Custom `PHP` and another `Laravel 5.4`. I have set some value in `session` variable using custom PHP using `$_SESSION`. And Now after login its redirect to laravel .
Now my question is how can I get this `Session` variable inside `laravel`.

Comment: Do you want to get session in laravel controller or in any view file?

Comment: inside laravel controller.

Comment: I think it's not possible, but try like first start the session and then use `$_SESSION[]`

Comment: i would recommend using database to store the data and redirect to the site that using laravel with a token `eg: http://example.laravel/home?_token=somethingRandom`, then you can use the token to retrieve the data from the database.

Comment: Or if it's small data just send it with the URL ex. `https://yourdomain.com?myData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel doesn't use native PHP sessions since [Laravel 4.1](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/releases).

> We are no longer using Symfony's (and therefore PHP's) session
>   handling facilities, and are using a custom solution that is simpler
>   and easier to maintain

In Laravel you want to use `Session::` facade or `session()` global helper to work with sessions:

```
// Saving value.
session()->put('key', 'value');

// Gettinng value.
session('key');
```

So you cannot access session data from another PHP application,

But you may be able to access the session from another Laravel app if you are using the same storage for session management for both apps (`Redis`, `Memcached`, shared session folder, ...) and you use the same `APP_KEY` (look in your `.env` file) and the same cookie identifier (look in your `config\session.php` file) in both apps.

Comment: Actually I m saving value from custom php and want to get this data in laravel.

Comment: @raj I think this means you cant.  You will need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: @Raj please see my updated answer. basically you can't do it.

Comment: @TobyAllen yes. I've added an explanation too

Comment: Could you provide the link, from where you've used the blockquote?

Comment: @linktoahref https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/releases search for "Improved Session Engine"

Answer (score 1):

you can use `session()` helper function. or `Session` Facade.

suppose you want to put something in session you can use

```
Session::put('key', 'this is something in session');
```

if you want to access the same

`echo Session::get('key') //outputs this is something in session`

Comment: Actually I m saving value from custom php using $_SESSION.and want to get this data in laravel using Session Facade.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the Session facade by using the proper namespace `\Session`

Comment: Are you trying to use it on the front-end?  This is how I used the Session facade in a project in the past: `@if(\Session::has('feedback')) do x, y, z`.  `has()` returns a bool value but you can use `get()` to access the actual value.  edit:  Nevermind just saw your new comment about using it on the back-end